# Xcode 4 : how to have the folder name of each opened project displayed in the Window menu?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, directory

In Xcode 3.x, it was very practical, when you have several Xcode project opened in parallel, to know what is the folder of each project. This info was given in the list of the opened project in the "Window" menu.

It was very useful as it allows to find easily a defined version of a project when you work on several versions in parallel.

How to have the name of the project folders associated to each project displayed in the "Window" menu ?

Is there an option somewhere ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could Command-click the file icon next to the title in the window's title bar. This shows the path to the file (in this case the project or workspace file) in any Cocoa app. You can even click one of the entries in the popup menu to open that folder in Finder.